# $p$-adic topology on a finitely generated module

Tags: modules, p-adic-number-theory, finitely-generated

Suppose that I have a finitely generated $\mathbb Z_p$-module $M$.
I have read that there is a "$p$-adic topology" on it.

My questions are:

- I have the product topology on the free group $\bigoplus_{i = 1}^n \mathbb Z_p$, and a homomorphism $\bigoplus_{i = 1}^n \mathbb Z_p \rightarrow M$. Is the $p$-adic topology the quotient topology on $M$?
- Do I actually need the module $M$ to be finitely generated?

Comment: The basis of open sets are the $p^k M$. If $M$ is finitely generated then $\forall k, a\in p^kM \implies a=0$ so the topology is Hausdorff and $M=\varprojlim M/p^k M$ is profinite. Yes it is the same as the quotient topology inherited from $\Bbb{Z}_p^n\to M$. It fails for the non-finitely generated $M=\Bbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: $\ker(\Bbb{Z}_p^n\to M)$ is a $\Bbb{Z}_p$-module so necessarily free and closed.

Comment: @reuns Thank you for the answer! Would you like to post it as an answer so that I can accept it?